# Problem with WIFI

Tags: pi-3b+, wireless, raspi-config, raspberry-pi-os-buster, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a Pi 3B + and installed bullseyes ago to two month  and not it detected wireless wifi, it say No wireless.
I does tried with raspi-config, enable wifi and it say no wireless.
so i does tried RPI update and no succed.
please help me, i dont know that do.

[image]

Comment: Please add a photo of the board to the question and the result of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Have you set the WiFi country?

Comment: What is the output of `ls /sys/class/net`?

Comment: i can't set the wifi country, it isn't  on service, i can't set since raspi-config. i will intent make ls/sys but not found wifi

Comment: Did you set the country properly when you installed the system?